# Storing request Id and request object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app which queries a database.

I want to provide a feature in my app where the user can cancel a running query.

I have a `requestId(uuid)` call and I'm mapping it to each request object and storing it in some storage. The user can cancel a request based on the request ID (hit an end point with the request ID). Each request is handled by the a callback.

In the callback, I have:

```
req.on("close", function() {});
```

Which is closing the request.

I am using [snowflake-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snowflake-sdk) for running query in my nowflake database.

```
var statement = connection.execute({
    sqlText: sql,
    complete: function (err, stmt, rows) {}
});
req.on("close", function() {
    statement.cancel(function(err, stmt) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Unable to abort statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Successfully aborted statement');
        }
    });
});
```

The `req` object is being passed to the function, `req` will be an HTTP request.

Now, the issue is how to generate the close event and how to map each cancel request to the original close request.

I also wanted to know, are there any suggestions ? Is this the right way to do this in NodeJS ? And what will be right way to store the request ID and request object, something like reddish or cache or session ?

Comment: The callback is not closing the request, it is called when the request was closed. So the question is: how is a running request closed — if the API supports this. Which API are you using?

Comment: @BlackJack I have edited the question.

Comment: Please include more of your code, for example where is `req` coming from and what is this function he is being passed to?

Comment: `http.ClientRequest` from node.js doesn't emit a `'close'` event, so what is `req` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

My question is why would even bother using a http request? In theory, Snowflake sdk wrapped up all http request used to execute/cancel query. Why are you using `req` object as a http request?